# ViewPager and AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-asynctask

Есть activity, на которой располагается фрагмент c ViewPager. Данные для фрагмента подгружаются из сети при помощи AsyncTaskLoader. Фрагмент реализует интерфейс LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<...>

В activity:

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return countPage;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.v(TAG, "getItem() called()");
            currentId = new Random().nextInt(countSites);
            return StoryFragment().newInstance(currentId);
        }
    });
```

В Фрагменте:

```
public static StoryFragment newInstance(int siteId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SITE_ID, siteId);
    StoryFragment storyFragment = new StoryFragment();
    storyFragment.setArguments(args);
    return storyFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    currentSiteId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SITE_ID);
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate() called, currentId" + currentSiteId);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()
                 .initLoader(PAGE_LOADER_ID, null, this);                                                 

     getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()
                  .getLoader(PAGE_LOADER_ID)
                  .forceLoad();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story, container, false);

    // ...
    Log.v(TAG, " onCreateView() - " + currentSiteId);
    return v;
}

@Override
public Loader<Document> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id == PAGE_LOADER_ID) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreateLoader called(), currentId = " + currentSiteId);
        // далее получение данных из сети
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Document> loader, Document data) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onLoadFinished() called, currentId = " + currentSiteId);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Document> loader) {

}
```

Логи при старте:

```
onCreate() called, currentId = 0
onCreateLoader() called, currentId = 0
onCreate() called, currentId = 1
onCreateView() called, currentId = 0
onCreateView() called, currentId = 1
onCreateFinished() called, currentId = 1
```

создается текущий фрагмент, он получает currentId = 0 и соседний фрагмент, который получает currentId = 1, но после получения данных из сети первый фрагмент почему-то имеет cuurentId = 1 (последний лог), из-за этого не могу правильно обработать данные из сети.

Comment: Добавьте код из viewPager

Comment: @Asgard по существу нечего добавлять, для простоты выпилил сейчас всю работу с данными и пытаюсь разобраться с поведение currentId. Гарантирую, что currentId в фрагменте с ViewPager нигде не изменяю.

Comment: @denis, лоадеры - жуткая непонятная фигня. Получайте лучше данные из сети с помощью RxJava (+Retrofit).

Comment: а у тебя наверное currentSiteId static?